# Write json String directly in SpringMVC

Tags: spring-mvc

In my spring-mvc application, the client requests with a key and I lookup the associated value  in Couchbase. From Couchbase I get a json object as a String, as my application doesn't need to do anything with it I just want this to be written out.

But Spring sees that I want to write a String, and passes it to jackson which then writes it as a json string - adding in quotation marks and escaping the internals.

Simplest example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/thing", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public DeferredResult<String> getThing() {
    final DeferredResult<String> result = new DeferredResult<>();
    // in future
    result.setResult("{}");
    return result;
}
```

Returns: `"{}"`

I'm thinking of making a serialised json wrapper and a custom serialiser for jackson to just output it's contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the StringHttpMessageConverter with `application/json` as a supportedMediaType:

```
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value = "application/json" />
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
```

This did get the String responses output as-is.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use   org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/example", headers = "Accept=application/json")
@ResponseBody
@Transactional
public ResponseEntity<String> example(@RequestParam(value = "documentId", required = true) Integer documentId) {

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

    SomeDTO result = SomeDTO.findDocument(documentId);
    if (result == null) {
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(headers, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<String>(result.toJson(), headers,HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

beside, you could use [Flexjson](http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/) to tranfer Oject to Json String.